# How can I customize Google Chrome shortcut keys?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, google-chrome, window-manager, productivity

I want Google Chrome to close the current tab when I press F8.

On Windows, this can easily be achieved using the Chrome extension 'AutoControl'.

I'm fairly sure AutoHotkey could handle it well too.

There are Chrome extensions that allow customizing shortcut keys, but it only works on website tabs and not on other tabs like chrome://bookmarks/ which I use very frequently.

The reason why it's not a problem on Windows is the low level [hook API](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks), has Ubuntu Linux a similar API that would allow such a functionality?

I currently use X11 because of my NVIDIA card, and might want to use Wayland in the future, I don't think I will use a special window manager other from the default one.

It should be reasonably easy to set up, and not cause unwanted side effect.